Can ligaments degenerate?
Tendons can degenerate due to repeated strains that overcome its adaptability capability.
Can ligaments degenerate too? If so how to prevent/heal it?
Some insight of the degeneration process is welcome.

Welcome to Medical Sciences! Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the reasons mentioned in this meta post, this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

"Degenerate" implies something I wouldn't intuitively ascribe to tendons and ligaments. Tendons and ligaments both can be damaged, and both, even damaged, can be repaired to a certain degree with physical therapy. Both may easily weaken with disuse.
